# Physics Book Recommendation Request

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, self-learning, book-recommendation

### General Requirements

- Physics for Mathematicians
- Philosophy + Foundations
- Mathematical Derivation of Theories

I want to know if there is a physics book for mathematicians. I attempted to read some traditional books in the branch, but I am having difficulties with the physical thinking process. I want some book that talks about philosophy, the foundations of physics and have the derivation of the theories in a very clear mathematical sense.

Comment: what kind of physics are you looking for? or what type of physics are you working on right now? If you are just doing classical physics, it is mostly just trig. However, one thing that is extremely useful to understand is linear algebra and the so called $\textbf{i,j,k}$ vector components.

Comment: That is, when we are dealing with force vectors, we will want to find out the $i,j,k$ (or xyz) contributions.

Comment: What's your background?That's important because most of the available texts on physics written for mathematicians are quite advanced,requiring graduate level mathematics.I think you'll find my response to this related question very helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/950672/very-mathematical-general-physics-book?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

The Feynmann Lectures on Physics are not specifically aimed at mathematicians, but they are excellent, especially on the subject of the foundations and the philosophy. I have no hesitation in recommending them.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking at classical mechanics, I would recommend [***Spivak* - Physics for Mathematicians, Mechanics I**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0914098322). Which discusses the foundational side of classical mechanics without lacking rigor.